# What is allocation "unused" in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

While investigating a node with shards on disk not referenced as "active" by the cluster, I found an allocation state: `unused`.
This state is referenced in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-shards-stores.html), however I found no explanation about it.

> The status of the store copy, whether it is used as a primary, replica or not used at all

Can someone please explain the purpose(s) of it?

**Edit**: Given comments it should be noted that the cluster was green and all primaries and replicas of all indices were present at the time I found those unused shards.

As of now all these shards in `unused` state (some were older than a year) disappeared. The operation that happened was to reduce replication on an index. This operation removed **all** unused shards even if they belonged to other indices. It should be noted that every month a new index is created and another is deleted so previously mentioned operation does not seem to explain the behavior solely.

Answer (score 1):

i think this could happen in an index with 2 shards and 1 replica per shard, so in a 2 node cluster you'd have (shard1, replica2) on one node and (shard2, replica1) on the other. a new node is added to the cluster and ES decides it is "better" or "faster" than one of the nodes and migrates one replica to it, so the previous copy of the replica becomes "unused" (it won't receive updates). or perhaps if your index settings changed to reduce the number of replicas, some of them become "unused" and don't receive updates.

Comment: Thanks Tom.
I also think that it's a good assumption of "how this happens".


But **why ES keeps it?** Some "unused" shards are very old (more than a year) and if they're kept as-is I'm not sure it'll be a faster operation if they have to become active again compared to a full copy.

I have many assumptions about this state and found no complete answer as of now.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that there is not much information on the unused shards in elasticsearch documentation so only way to get some information is by looking at the source code.

If you look at the [getAllocationStatus](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/shards/TransportIndicesShardStoresAction.java#L219) method which decide the shard status you will get to know how ES deciding shard is `unused`.

Above method code is below

```
 private IndicesShardStoresResponse.StoreStatus.AllocationStatus getAllocationStatus(String index, int shardID,
                                                                                                DiscoveryNode node) {
                for (ShardRouting shardRouting : routingNodes.node(node.getId())) {
                    ShardId shardId = shardRouting.shardId();
                    if (shardId.id() == shardID && shardId.getIndexName().equals(index)) {
                        if (shardRouting.primary()) {
                            return IndicesShardStoresResponse.StoreStatus.AllocationStatus.PRIMARY;
                        } else if (shardRouting.assignedToNode()) {
                            return IndicesShardStoresResponse.StoreStatus.AllocationStatus.REPLICA;
                        } else {
                            return IndicesShardStoresResponse.StoreStatus.AllocationStatus.UNUSED;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return IndicesShardStoresResponse.StoreStatus.AllocationStatus.UNUSED;
            }
```

**As you can note, if shard is having a primary flag, its marked as primary shard, after that if shard is assigned to a node, it's marked as replica shard and if both of above conditions don't match its marked as `unused`.**

I believe unless shard is copied completely Elasticsearch won't assign it a node(refer [shard allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html) for more details) so it will be marked as unused, but for some reason if node from which its being copied is died or disconnected and can't be recovered it may always be in `unused` status.

Comment: I believe that it should be noted that at the time I found this unused shards the cluster was green and all primaries and replicas were correctly present.

Comment: @BastienSemene, yes cluster status will be in green only, if you notice cluster statue will be yellow or RED if one or more primary or replica shards are missing, and cluster state doesn't include the `unused` state of shards, hope this clears your doubts reg cluster state

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I already upvoted your answer, however we still don't know what's the purpose of this state so I can't accept it as an answer.